# Issue generating redmine report in PDF

Tags: ubuntu, redmine

I am using Redmine for issue tracking and now I need to generate a report of all the issues and their states.

The problem is that, when I press de PDF button at the bottom of the issue list, to download the PDF report, I cannot open it, it gives the error: 
"Format error: not a PDF or corrupted"

The first thing I tried to do was downloading it again, and noticed that the downloaded sizes for both files were different.

The first thing I thought is that it didn't have enough RAM assigned to the VM. Tried fixing this and got the same problem. So I started thinking that maybe it was something wrong with the Redmine version I was using (I was using an older version, 1.3 I think) so I updated to the 2.6.0.stable and got the exact same error and I don't know what could be wrong.

More info:

- Database: PostreSQL;
- Running on xen hypervisor;
- Ubuntu 12.04 and then upgraded to 14.04 via the command line (a new version wasn't installed);

Anyone know have any ideas as to what else I could be looking for?

PS: I'm not an IT guy, the IT guys refuse to do anything to this VM unless it's related to backups.

Comment: Did you check the error logs?

Comment: I googled "Format error: not a PDF or corrupted" and it seems like that is an error from the FoxIt pdf viewer. It might be useful to save the pdf and try a different viewer. I sometimes find on my mac that the chrome viewer gets an error, but mac's built-in preview app shows the same pdf.

Comment: @joecullin I've tried that. Sumatra pdf simpy doesn't open it, foxit gives me that error and adobe throws another error I don't remember now (I'll try it mondat since I don't have adobe at home) but it was somethingsimilar to foxit's error